How many times did Zechariah request from God a child?
When we read through the NIV of Luke 1:13 - 14, it is clearly stated that Zechariah was told by the Angel of Lord that his 'prayer' had been heard from God. Was it that same time he was praying or was it several other times he came on duty? If be so for the first time of his prayer then perhaps the old man never needed a child so soon. But Luke stated a saliant point that they were both advanced in age and his wife was barren, claiming that she had been having sex with her husband but no production of a kid since barrenness is seen.

Luke 1:13, 14 - But the angel said to him: “Do not be afraid,
Zechariah; your prayer has been heard. Your wife Elizabeth will bear
you a son, and you are to call him John. He will be a joy and delight
to you, and many will rejoice because of his birth


Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Short Answer: The Bible does not specify the exact number of times Zechariah prayed for a child.

Luke 1:13 ESV - But the angel said to him, “Do not be afraid,
Zechariah, for your prayer has been heard, and your wife Elizabeth
will bear you a son, and you shall call his name John.

It is clear from Luke 1:13 that Zechariah had prayed for a child, as the angel said, “Your prayer has been heard.” Maybe this implies that Zechariah had been praying for a child for some time, not just during that specific instance when he was on duty in the temple.
Zechariah and his wife Elizabeth were both advanced in age. They had no children because Elizabeth was barren. This means that they had pleanty of time to pray. This situation is also similar to other biblical accounts where couples prayed for children over a long period, such as Abraham and Sarah.

Luke fills his first chapter with callbacks and allusions to the
miraculous of significant figures in Israel’s history. Zechariah and
Elizabeth are old and have no children: similar to how Abraham and
Sarah were before the birth of Isaac.
It was a sad thing in those days to have no children. In their
culture, having no children meant that your family line ended—Old
Testament characters (like Job and Jacob) were blessed with many
children. But being childless was a shameful thing. [1]

Therefore, I would say that it is likely that Zechariah had been praying for a child for many years before the angel appeared to him.

Thanks so much for your response as we dig deeper in His truth to convey better message to our people before our Pulpits: For the sake of the Cross, we remain steadfast.

Jesus told an important parable about the persistent widow as a model of prayer in Luke 18:1-8, especially V1 -

Then Jesus told his disciples a parable to show them that they should
always pray and not give up.

Now, it is well-known that women in Bible times, from at least the time of Sarah, Rebekah, Rachel, Hannah and Manoah's wife, to Elizabeth longed to have children and prayed often to have this divine blessing.
Based on this context, I would reasonably assume that Zechariah and his wife Elizabeth and prayed many, many times for a child.  Just how often they prayed we are not told, but I am certain it was much, much more than once.

Just because the Bible says 'prayer' in verse 13 doesn't escape the reality that the angel might be telling a lie...as imply in the very truth. We need to do some considerations from how the Ark Angel Gabriel from Heaven will come with an imbalance information which we as mortal scholars must get clues to the length of time they had spent together in marriage. If prayer is in the singular then the value matters and not volume.

@WisdomElijahTisdell - I am flabbergasted that you suggest that an angel of God would lie!!!  I find such a suggestion absurd.  In Koine Greek, the feminine singular if often used for a collective plural.

I am not saying that the Angel Gabriel lied....I might be suggesting and under the theory of hypothesis and hermeneutics, we are permitted to theologize a text until we come in with a dialogue for our audience to consume. Nonetheless, I am also aware that your latter response is also quite correct as imply yet let us as Theolog look at the text visibly firstly and then recommend the Greek or Hebrew canon interpretations. Keep soaring higher Commrade.

Zechariah prayed for a child when people around started asking him after 10 months into his marriage, whether something was wrong with his wife who was not giving him a child. He prayed each moon-month when Elizabeth became ' impure' on periods, hoping that next time  things would work out. Zechariah prayed each time he left home, hoping to hear 'good  news' from Elizabeth on his return. He prayed each time he returned home from a long journey,  sad to find that no little steps followed his dear wife. He prayed , remembering Abraham and Sarah, while noticing grey hair on his head and Elizabeth's.  For him prayer for a child had now become a lingering emotion.
And, no one can count an emotion that stays  with you 60x60x24x365.25!

You keep track of all my sorrows. You have collected all my tears in your bottle ( Psalm 56:8).

Yes, when teardrops are bottled, they stop getting counted, and are measured by  volume  or by weight !

Many thankfulness for your respond. May the weight of your response enlighten others as well.
